# Is there a valid way to wrap a dt and a dd with an HTML element?

Tags: html, validation, semantics, w3c, specifications

I wish HTML could do something semantically equivalent to this;

```
<dl class="main-list">
    <definitionitem>
        <dt>Some Thing</dt>
            <dd>You know it!</dd>
        <dt>Another Thing</dt>
            <dd>Word.</dd>
    </definitionitem>
    <definitionitem>
        <dt>Stuff</dt>
            <dd>Alright!</dd>
    </definitionitem>
</dl>
```

However, since the closest I've come is something I'm not 100% satisfied with the semantics of;

```
<div class="redundant-wrapper">
    <dl class="main-list">
        <dt>Some Thing</dt>
            <dd>You know it!</dd>
        <dt>Another Thing</dt>
            <dd>Word.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="another-main-list">
        <dt>Stuff!</dt>
            <dd>Alright!</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I was wondering if anyone has any other ideas of how you might do this?

Also, the reason the items would be grouped is because they are visually grouped in the content that is being marked up. Imagine a dictionary page, with a single definition list, where each definition is in an inset box that is floated left. I run into this situation all the time.

Comment: There's no 'syntactically valid,' or even 'valid at all' way to wrap a `dt` and `dd` together; the *only valid* children of a `dl` are `dt` and `dd`.

Comment: I understand that it's not valid. What I'm wondering is, how would people semantically group together a single dt/dd pair as one "definition item", since, semantically, you could make an argument that a definition is a semantic child of a "definition list", itself having children of dt/dd.

Comment: @JosiahSprague — You'd put the `<dd>` element after the `<dt>` element and before any other `<dt>` elements.

Comment: Quentin, that doesn't wrap them in a definition element that can be easily manipulated as one in the DOM.

Comment: @JosiahSprague — No, it doesn't. As David Thomas said, there is no way to do that.

Comment: I've updated the wording of my question to be more clear

Comment: There was a proposal to do exactly that in XHTML 2.0. [The `<di>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-list.html#edef_list_di). But XHTML 2.0 never made it, so your request is off. Edit: Ha, I see you're quoting from that page already. Oh well.

Comment: Interesting fact about <di> in XHTML 2.0. I never knew that. I wonder if any browsers ended up implementing that. *off to test*

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, Ian Hickson (HTML spec editor) is [convinced](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0193.html) that this is a CSS problem, not an HTML one:

> This shouldn't be necessary. It's a limitation of CSS.
>
> The right solution is for CSS to provide some pseudo-element or other
> mechanism that introduces an anonymous container into the rendering
> tree  that wraps the elements you want to wrap.

At the same time, fantasai (CSS spec editor) is convinced in [contrary](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0231.html):

> I don't think this is a CSS problem. I think it's an HTML problem.
> Pseudo-elements are a non-trivial thing to spec, and a non-trivial
> thing to implement, and a comparatively confusing thing to use.

Nevertheless, Ian apparently ignores that and continues to be detached from reality.

There are same problems with [`LEGEND`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/200) (that must be first direct child of `FIELDSET` according to HTML spec), [`FIGCAPTION`](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12835) (that must be first/last direct child of `FIGURE`), and `LI` (direct child of `UL`/`OL`).

As for `DT`/`DD` in particular, I personally [use](https://tanalin.com/en/blog/2014/12/dt-dd/) `UL` list with `DL` inside each of `LI`:

```
<ul>
    <li><dl>
        <dt>Lorem</dt>
        <dd>Lorem definition</dd>
    </dl></li>

    <li><dl>
        <dt>Ipsum</dt>
        <dd>Ipsum definition</dd>
    </dl></li>
</ul>
```

So we have `DL` to make relation between `DT` and `DD`, and `UL` list to make them all belong to one list.

**Update (2016-11-14):** The HTML standard ([WHATWG version](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-dl-element) for now) now (since 2016-10-31) [allows](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/5454d702e0262749aba55576dda32c48e0e498f0) the `DIV` element (optionally intermixed with so-called script-supporting elements `SCRIPT`, `TEMPLATE`) to be direct children of `DL` elements. W3C’s [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) does *not* account for this change yet, but the experimental [HTML5.org validator](https://checker.html5.org/) does.

**Update (2017-01-18):** Turns out the spec does [not](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1937#issuecomment-255339408) allow more than one nested `DIV` wrapper for `DT`/`DD`, so usefulness of the feature in practice is actually very limited and the `UL`→`LI`→`DL` approach described here is still relevant.

Comment: I love this idea. It's not semantically perfect, but as you stated, the spec doesn't really allow for that. This is the most semantic idea I've heard so far. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: The HTML spec has now changed and allows `div` in `dl`. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-dl-element

Comment: @zcorpan Wow, thanks, Simon. That’s a sort of paradigm shift in the HTML world. Too bad the change is very narrow and solely about grouping `DT`/`DD` elements, while generic containers are still _not_ allowed _everywhere_ — e.g. for wrapping `LEGEND` and `FIGCAPTION`. I would prefer this to be solved on CSS side though, since that would allow to have different sets of grouped elements depending e.g. on media queries, but having this at least in HTML and at least for `DT`/`DD` is anyway better than nothing.

Comment: You can use https://checker.html5.org/ instead, it has the dl-div change implemented. It is more up-to-date and tracks the WHATWG spec rather than the W3C one where there are differences.

Comment: If an idea is difficult to spec and implement, two (of many) possibilities are 1-the idea is bad 2-the underlying technology is too rigid. As for definition lists, a container around `dt` & `dd` does not add much semantic value and makes me think Ian is not so "detached from reality"

Comment: @Doug The point is that CSS people say this is an HTML issue, while HTML people say this is a CSS issue. So we have a vicious circle here. I would prefer a CSS solution since it would allow to have different layout depending on e.g. Media Queries which HTML with hard-coded containers is not capable of. But an HTML solution would be _better than nothing_.

Comment: @Doug: Semantically, while a container inside `dl` may not add a whole lot of value, _some_ way to tie `dt` and `dd` together would be extremely valuable. `dt` probably should've always **been** a container for `dd`, because that's how it's described: "Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more `dt` elements followed by one or more `dd` elements" ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)) — sure sounds like a container to me! And things like multi-column `dl` lists are a nightmare right now, with `dt`+`dd` groups getting chopped up willy-nilly by col breaks.

Comment: I think it's very important to keep in mind that when we're talking about "Specifications" there's two sources. WHATWG is "less official" than W3C (depending on who you're talking to). 

HOWEVER. As of October 2017, wrapping a set of <dd> and <dt> tags with a <div> tag is acceptable both according to WHATWG ( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-dl-element ) and W3C ( https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-dl-element ).

Answer (score 16):

there's a [repo about dd-dt wrapping](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1937). According to the html spec whatwg it is [OK to wrap each](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) dd & dt with div tag inside DL.

```
<dl>
   <div>
     <dt>Bolster</dt>
     <dd>to support, strengthen, or fortify</dd>
   </div>
   <div>
     <dt>Capitalize</dt>
     <dd>to use to your advantage</dd>
   </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here we are in 2018! [CSS grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) is well supported, and this offers yet another possible solution / workaround to the problem if the main goal is to control the positioning of the `dt`/`dd`...

HTML

```
<dl>
    <dt>Favorite food</dt>
    <dd>Pizza</dd>

    <dt>Favorite drink</dt>
    <dd>Beer</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}
```

(You can tweak the values of `grid-template-columns` to match your specific design requirements.)

This doesn't "solve" the limitations of the spec, but I thought it helpful since you specifically mentioned concerns about semantic markup. As I mentioned above, there are limitations to what grid can do, but if the goal is to control the layout of the `dt`/`dd` I think this might be the most semantic way to do it that is still valid HTML.

Comment: Note: This assumes that you don’t have multiple <dd> elements which the spec allows.